# This statement is true when manually checked but compiler doesn't think so

Tags: c++

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/game-of-two-stacks/problem
So this is a question on hackerrank. I was practicing stacks so decided to make my own stack class.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jiMda7q1ANn-4roVRuwmy1nKkDzeQMmH/view?usp=sharing This is a link to the full code.

```
 while(stack2.top > -1 && (stack1.top < a.size() - 1))
```

this is a loop condition that is not executing although it is true.The problem is the 2nd part of the condition,the compiler thinks that it is false but it should be true since stack1.top = -1 and a.size = 5.

Edit:

```
    int twoStacks(int x, vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
    {
        //So i skipped some code in this function to shorten it.
        
   // BELOW LOOP CONDITION IS THE ISSUE.
     while(stack2.top > -1 && (stack1.top < a.size() - 1)) 
        {
            sum = sum + stack2.stacktop();  
            stack2.top--;
            while(sum > x && (stack1.top < a.size() - 1)) 
            {
                stack1.top++;
                sum = sum - stack1.stacktop();
            }
            count2 = a.size() - stack1.top - 1 + b.size() - stack2.top -1; 
            if(sum <=x && count2 > count) 
                count = count2;
        }
        return count; 
    }
```

This loop wont even execute(not even once) even though the conditions are satisfied. this happens only when stack1.top = -1 and not otherwise. the Top variable is normal int and not unsigned.

here is a testcase that causes problem.

4 24 81 ( 4 is the size of vector a , 24 is the size of vector b and sum should be less than equal to 81).

0 12 12 19 (vector a which is pushed into stack1 right to left since a[0] is top element)

15 6 1 18 7 15 5 14 14 1 12 15 8 16 14 2 14 9 13 12 18 19 3 18 (vector b which is pushed into stack2 same as vector a)

I want the while loop to work with the condition since the condition is true. I don't understand why it thinks it's false (stack1.top is -1 and a.size() is 5 which should give -1 < 4 which is true.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: `This is a link to the code. I don't know if u can upload a txt file here.` you have to include the code the same way you did with the smaller snipped you already have in your question.

Comment: @t.niese the code was big so didn't wanna fill up all the space with it.

Comment: @DhruvDubey That's why we ask for a [mre]. *Minimal* means what it says.

Comment: @DhruvDubey you then need to boil it down to a [mcve]. Links to external sites can become unreachable anytime, so they must not contain any critical information. Links should only be used as an addition to provide a reference. But the question (or also an answer) has to be understandable without the need to follow the link.

Comment: @DhruvDubey: Even if you post all of your code, it will not fill all the screen. Instead, a scrollable view of the code will be in your question. Therefore, posting all of your code would still have been better than an external link. However, an [mre] would still have been better.

Answer (score 1):

You have issue because of mixing signed and unsigned value,

`a.size() - 1` would be really big number when `a` is empty.

`stack1.top` would be converted to big number when negative.

It should be:

```
if (! (stack1.top + 1 < a.size()))
```

Comment: But 'a' is never empty. it is already provided to us in the question. I'm sorry i should have mentioned that a and b are two vectors given to us by the question using whom i have made 2 stacks, stack1 and stack2. Both are array based stacks. Basically a.size() is fixed throughout the program.

Comment: issue is similar with `stack1.top == -1`. provided fix doesn't works for `stack1.top == -2` though then.

Comment: why would stack1.top become a big number though when negative ? it is not unsigned it is a normal int.

Comment: `a.size()` is `unsigned`, and `signed < unsigned` promote `signed` to `unsigned`.

Comment: if this were the problem would replacing a.size() with a variable " int a_size = a.size();" help solve the problem ? This actually didn't work so if it was supposed to maybe the actual problem is something else ?